# Use is or are with the plural "statistics"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have the following sentence:

> "Statistics is my passion and I am always eager to accept new
>   challenges"

I am not sure about the statistics and the is.

Is this correct? Because statistics is plural and so do I have to use are? Or should I use just

> statistic is my passion

in this context, so singular version of statistics?

Comment: This is the **same question** as asking why one words like *aesthetics, physics, economics, mathematics* are normally considered singular.  This happens with a great many *-ics* nouns. Please search for answers there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends how you are using it.

If you are speaking of the mathematical discipline of *statistics*, then it is alright to use it as a singular noun as you would with mathematics, economics etc.

However if referring to some specific sets of figures, then it should be conjugated as a plural: e.g. *Statistics show that women live longer than men.*

Comment: Yes, it’s just like with *physics*.

Answer (score 0):

I think your sentence could be expanded to "The field of statistics is my passion..." .  As Statistics is being used to denote one area of study, you would use "is" rather than "are".

Answer (score 0):

The field of study named statistics is a different (and usually singular) word from the data points referred to as statistics (usually a plural word). [
Refer: http://thefreedictionary.com/statistics ]

When the word is used for the subject of statistics, rules applicable to any particular subject apply to it without any modification. In particular the sentence in question will have the same structure as of sentences like "Civics is my passion..." or " Chemistry is my passion ...".